# Can a Raspberry Pi Zero work with a bluetooth adapter?

Tags: bluetooth

Is it possible to use a bluetooth adapter (usually BLE) with a Raspberry Pi Zero? I don't mean the one that comes with built in wireless and bluetooth, I mean the one without wireless.
[image: A bluetooth adapter/dongle like this one]

Comment: My bad. I meant that raspberry pi zero that doesn't come with wireless.

Comment: what difference would that make?

Comment: the best answer is "perhaps" ... it really depends if the adapter is supported by raspberry pi OS

Comment: The Pi-Zero marked with W

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You will need to make sure that the specific bluetooth adapter is supported though. An example list of supported bluetooth adapters is at https://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Bluetooth_adapters.